# Как записать объекты java из List в json в цикле?

Tags: java, json

```
File f = new File("c:\\file.json");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Person> snap = new Connector().getbyTrigger();
for (Person p : snap){  
try{
        mapper.writeValue(f, p);
        System.out.println("Успешно");
   }
}
```

В файле file.json сохраняется только один объект, последний. Как сделать так, чтобы в цикле записывались все объекты snap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты постоянно переписываешь контент файла. Просто передай списком как параметр в функцию.

```
mapper.writeValue(f, snap);
```

Comment: попробую. Но если это всё же нужно сделать в цикле. Например, Person - класс, содержащий много полей (класс-сущность, на который отображаются таблицы бд) и самих объектов много. Можно сделать запись в json последовательно частями или рекурсивно?

Comment: Можно но зачем если за тебя все это делает jackson?